# NSDate odd behaviour

Tags: macos, nsdate

I'm trying to use `+[NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString]` on Mac OS X (Snow Leopard) to get tomorrow's date.

I was expecting that it would return tomorrow's date at 12AM but it returns tomorrow's date at 12PM. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Code:

```
date = [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:@"tomorrow"];

NSLog(@"DATE: %@", date);
```

Output: `DATE: 2012-08-23 12:00:00 +0100`

Comment: From the `dateWithNaturalLanguageString:` documentation: "It may give unexpected results, and its use is strongly discouraged. To create a date object from a string, you should use a date formatter object instead (see NSDateFormatter and Data Formatting Guide)."

Comment: I've looked at the documentation and no, doesn't look like a bug. If you want the date to be midnight, you'd have to use something like "tomorrow at midnight"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **tomorrow at midnight** instead tomorrow like this:

```
date = [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:@"tomorrow at midnight"];

NSLog(@"DATE: %@", date);
```

**Output:**

2012-08-24 00:00:00 +0100

---

**Note:**

You also can use **Tomorrow at  < time > AM** if You want specific time, for example:

```
date = [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:@"tomorrow at 1:00 AM"];
```

or midnight:

```
date = [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:@"tomorrow at 12:00 AM"];
```